# Using braces when creating a new class instance

Tags: c#

I have seen in a code a use of braces to directly inform the values of the variables of the concerned class when creating a new instance.

**Exemple (see employee3)**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //I KNOW THIS.
        //Employee employee1 = new Employee(100, "Mike", 2000, 3);

        //I ALSO KNOW THIS.
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
            employee2.ID = 101;
            employee2.Name = Henry;
            employee2.Salary = 3000;
            employee2.Experience = 4;

        //BUT THIS IS THE FIRST TIME I HAVE SEEN THIS.
        Employee employee3 = new Employee()
            { ID = 102, Name = "John", Salary = 3000, Experience = 5 };
    }


class Employee
{
    //Employee(iD, name, salary, experience)
    //{
    //    ID = iD;
    //    Name = name;
    //    Salary = salary;
    //    Experience = experience;
    //}

    //Employee() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}
```

What do these braces mean, what are they called, can they be otherwise useful...

Comment: Are you calling the braces parentheses? It's called an object initializer. They can also be used to initialize collections: `var x = new List<int> { 0, 2, 4 };`

Comment: That syntax is called "object initializer syntax".

Comment: It's another syntax for exactly the same actions. Don't worry about it.
`A a = new A(); a.field = 1;` can be written as `A a = new A() { field=1 }`
You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: Ok, thank you guys, I'll look up this.

Comment: Even if you're using c# 6 you can initialize properties in the class definition https://csharp.today/c-6-features-auto-property-initializers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used to initialise fields on the `Employee` object instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or
>   properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a
>   constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.